# Getting java.lang.assertion failure error when saving mule flow - mule studio

Tags: mule, mule-studio

For sometime now, I am always getting java.lang.assertionError error in mule studio whenever I save a flow via graphical editor. I don't get any error if I directly make changes to XML. Anyone has faced this issue before?

I see the below error in eclipse problems tab,

Element: Response is not allowed to be child of element HTTP

Answer (score 0):

I made a copy of flow, and delete the original, and rename the copy. It works for me.